# Supporting multiple screens in AIR with Flash Professional CC

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, screen-size, tween

I know this is one of the most asked questions, but this question is quite different.

I have a movieclip called `ball`, which has a **classic tween** (neither a motion tween nor a tween made with AS3), and I want to adapt it for Android devices. I already know how to deal this problem with movieclips that *don't* have a tween, but I don't know how to work with movieclips that have classic tweens.

It would be a waste of time if I had to use AS3 to make tweens, because the app is mostly an animation.
How can I fix this problem?

If I had to make an AS3 Tween, it would be like this:

```
var ball:MovieClip = new bola();
var tween1:Tween = new Tween(ball, "x", 0, 120, None.easeNone, 1.5, true);
addChild(ball);
```

`bola` would be the class used to export the graphic from the library.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple screen? And Classic Tween.

Comment: By multiple screens I mean the different screen resolutions on Android devices, and by Classic Tween, it's one of the three interpolations available in Flash Professional CS6.

Comment: Guess!!! On different screen resolutions your animation is not scaling. You want your graphics to be scaled (fitted) on the target device screens?

Comment: Exactly. I could do it with static (no tween) movieclips, but not with moving movieclips with an in-stage tween like the Classic Tween.